# debuild error: override_dh_auto_install:: command not found

Tags: ubuntu, debian, packaging

I'm learning to build debian packages by following: https://wiki.debian.org/Packaging/Intro?action=show&redirect=IntroDebianPackaging

As advised in above article, When I run **`debuild -us -uc`**, It fails with below error:

```
# debuild -us -uc
 dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -D -us -uc
dpkg-buildpackage: warning: using a gain-root-command while being root
dpkg-buildpackage: source package hithere
dpkg-buildpackage: source version 1.0-1
dpkg-buildpackage: source distribution unstable
dpkg-buildpackage: source changed by XXXXXXX XXXXX <xxxxxxxxxxxxx@nnnn.com>
 dpkg-source --before-build hithere-1.0
dpkg-buildpackage: host architecture amd64
 fakeroot debian/rules clean
debian/rules: line 1: fg: no job control
   dh_testdir
   dh_auto_clean
    make -j1 clean
rm -f hithere hithere.o
   dh_clean
debian/rules: line 4: override_dh_auto_install:: command not found
debian/rules: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `('
debian/rules: line 5: ` $(MAKE) DESTDIR=$$(pwd)/debian/hithere prefix=/usr install'
dpkg-buildpackage: error: fakeroot debian/rules clean gave error exit status 2
debuild: fatal error at line 1376:
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -D -us -uc failed
```

It says **`override_dh_auto_install:: command not found`**. I am little lost here searching google to fix above error but have not been successful yet. Any pointers would be of great help.

BTW, I am running this procedure on Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit

Answer (score 0):

I made a really stupid mistake. I forgot to add **`#!/usr/bin/make -f`** at the beginning of my **`debian/rules`** file. Things are working now.